# Text region extraction by finding co-ordinates of text from an image

Tags: tesseract, leptonica

I am developing an image processing software that extracts/crops and enhances this cropped single page form from an image taken from a cellphone camera.The form has no rectangular boundaries to simplify the process of extraction.Yes it is a white background black text format but nothing apart from that is fixed.Now some Text will be present which will verify that the image is of the form required.So my questions are these.

1) Can i search for a specific regular expression using leptonica library itself or do i have to shift focus to other libraries like the tessarect API to do this.So far i have not found anything of this sort

2) Now suppose i know the text at the top left corner and the bottom right corner and i search it succesfully.Can i get the co-ordinates of the particular text that i am searching and then crop the image accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Leptonica doesn't do anything with text, it's an image processing library.

To enable acquiring position of the text, add `tessedit_create_hocr 1` to you Tesseract config file (or set this option whichever way you configure Tesseract if you're using it as a library).

The result is no longer a text file, but a UTF-8-encoded HTML file (note: it's not valid XML). Its format is self-explanatory. It will contain positions and dimensions of all words on all pages in pixels, as found on the input image. You need to parse that HTML, find the words you're looking for, and then get bounding boxed of those words.